# Three.js issue creating meshes outside of loader's load() function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I had difficulty exporting more than one texture using Blender's Three.js add-on, so had planned to work around it be separating the parts into separate meshes, but then came across the unexpected problem of the code not working when I created the meshes outside of the load() function. I've supplied an example below using a single model with a single mesh. The following works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>working</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000000;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script src="js/build/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>

        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            var container;

            var camera, scene, renderer, objects;

            var scaleAdj = 100;
            init();
            animate();

            function init() 
            {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 20000 );
                camera.position.set( 0, 500, 0 );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xcce0ff, 10, 10000 );

                var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

                loader.load( 'cube.json', function ( geometry, materials ) 
                {

                    var faceMaterial = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );

                    for ( var i = 0; i < 250; i ++ ) 
                    {

                        var x = ( ( i % 27 )  - 13.5 ) * (5 * scaleAdj) + THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 300 * scaleAdj);
                        var z = ( Math.floor( i / 27 ) - 13.5 ) * (5 * scaleAdj) + THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 300 * scaleAdj);

                        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, faceMaterial );

                        var s = THREE.Math.randFloat( 0.5, 2 ) * scaleAdj;
                        mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );

                        mesh.position.set( x, scaleAdj, z );
                        mesh.rotation.y = THREE.Math.randFloat( -0.25, 0.25 );

                        mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                        mesh.updateMatrix();

                        scene.add( mesh );

                    }

                } );

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff ) );

                // ground
                var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                var groundTexture = textureLoader.load( "texture.jpg" );
                groundTexture.wrapS = groundTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                groundTexture.repeat.set( 40, 40 );
                groundTexture.anisotropy = 16;

                var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, specular: 0x111111, map: groundTexture } );

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 20000, 20000 ), groundMaterial );
                mesh.position.y = 0;
                mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add( mesh );

                // Renderer

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color );

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                // Events

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }


            function onWindowResize( event ) {

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();

            }

            function render() {

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }



        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But this doesn't (I've annotated which sections contain the differences):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>not working</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000000;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script src="js/build/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>

        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            //--------------- difference number 1
            var obj_geometry;
            var obj_material;
            //-----------------------------------

            var container;

            var camera, scene, renderer, objects;

            var scaleAdj = 100;
            init();
            animate();

            function init() 
            {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 20000 );
                camera.position.set( 0, 500, 0 );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xcce0ff, 10, 10000 );


                //-------------------difference number 2--------------------
                var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

                loader.load( 'cube.json', function ( geometry, material ) 
                {
                    obj_geometry = geometry;
                    obj_material = material;
                });

                var faceMaterial = new THREE.MultiMaterial( obj_material);

                for ( var i = 0; i < 250; i ++ ) 
                {

                        var x = ( ( i % 27 )  - 13.5 ) * (5 * scaleAdj) + THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 300 * scaleAdj);
                        var z = ( Math.floor( i / 27 ) - 13.5 ) * (5 * scaleAdj) + THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 300 * scaleAdj);

                        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( obj_geometry, faceMaterial);

                        var s = THREE.Math.randFloat( 0.5, 2 ) * scaleAdj;
                        mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );

                        mesh.position.set( x, 0, z );
                        mesh.rotation.y = THREE.Math.randFloat( -0.25, 0.25 );

                        mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                        mesh.updateMatrix();

                        scene.add( mesh );

                }

                //--------------------------------------

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff ) );

                // ground
                var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                var groundTexture = textureLoader.load(  "texture.jpg" );
                groundTexture.wrapS = groundTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                groundTexture.repeat.set( 40, 40 );
                groundTexture.anisotropy = 16;

                var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, specular: 0x111111, map: groundTexture } );

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 20000, 20000 ), groundMaterial );
                mesh.position.y = 0;
                mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add( mesh );

                // Renderer

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color );

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                // Events

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }


            function onWindowResize( event ) {

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();

            }

            function render() {

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }



        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a copy of the contents of the cube.json file:

```
{
    "uvs":[[0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]],
    "faces":[43,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,43,4,7,6,5,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,43,0,4,5,1,0,0,1,2,3,0,4,7,1,43,1,5,6,2,0,0,1,2,3,1,7,6,2,43,2,6,7,3,0,0,1,2,3,2,6,5,3,43,4,0,3,7,0,0,1,2,3,4,0,3,5],
    "normals":[0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349],
    "metadata":{
        "generator":"io_three",
        "type":"Geometry",
        "normals":8,
        "vertices":8,
        "uvs":1,
        "version":3,
        "materials":1,
        "faces":6
    },
    "vertices":[1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,0.999999,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1],
    "materials":[{
        "DbgName":"Material",
        "colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5],
        "DbgIndex":0,
        "mapDiffuseWrap":["RepeatWrapping","RepeatWrapping"],
        "mapDiffuse":"texture.jpg",
        "shading":"phong",
        "depthTest":true,
        "opacity":1,
        "transparent":false,
        "colorDiffuse":[0.64,0.64,0.64],
        "mapDiffuseAnisotropy":1,
        "blending":"NormalBlending",
        "depthWrite":true,
        "visible":true,
        "specularCoef":50,
        "mapDiffuseRepeat":[1,1],
        "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
        "wireframe":false,
        "DbgColor":15658734
    }],
    "name":"CubeGeometry"
}
```

And here is [an attached texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRP7i.jpg) which could be used.

It might just be a trivial problem for some of the posters on here, and if so, thanks in advance for just letting me know what it is. If not, then the answer could be useful to a lot more people, and thanks for any help you can give on it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this, asynchronously:

```
var obj_geometry; // === undefined
var myMesh = new THREE.Mesh( obj_geometry ); //because undefined, same as calling new THREE.Mesh();

obj_geometry = geometry;//does nothing, mesh has no idea about this happening
obj_material = material;
```

When you construct a mesh, you've given it `undefined` for geometry, so i think it just calls `new Geometry()` inside the constructor. This mesh has been created with a unique isntance of empty `Geometry` and has nothing to do with your `obj_geometry`.

The solution here is to do:

```
var obj_geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var myMesh = new THREE.Mesh( obj_geometry ); //holds a reference to an empty "proxy"
```

then onLoad

```
loader.load( 'url' , function( geom ) {
  obj_geometry.merge(geom); //"FILL PREVIOUSLY CREATED GEOMETRY WITH DATA"
  obj_geometry.vertsNeedUpdate = true; // there's a few flags like this you need to turn on
}
```

OR

```
var myMesh = new THREE.Mesh();

loader.load( 'url', function( geom ) {

   myMesh.geometry = geom; //"PUT THE JUST CREATED GEOMETRY IN THE RIGHT PLACE"
   //myOtherMesh.geometry = geom; //if you have more places where this needs to end up
   //myThirdMesh.geometry = geom; //gets very cumbersome

}
```

Both are pretty cumbersome and not very intuitive :( i really dislike this part of three.js.

Comment: Thanks for that answer much appreciated, and hopefully useful for others too :)

Comment: Hi, sorry but I tried the first solution and wasn't able to get it to work. Perhaps I am misunderstanding or have missed something out.

Comment: var obj_geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
...   
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( 'cube.json', function ( geometry)    
{
  obj_geometry.merge(geometry);
  obj_geometry.vertsNeedUpdate = true;
  obj_geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
  obj_geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
  obj_geometry.lineDistancesNeedUpdate = true;
    
  obj_geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
  obj_geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
    
});
    
for ( var i = 0; i < 250; i ++ ) 
{
   ...    
   mesh = new THREE.Mesh( obj_geometry);
   ...
}

Comment: I am also having a problem making the myMesh var = new Three.Mesh(obj_geometry); , and then in the part where I create the multiple mesh instances making mesh = myMesh.clone();

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from pailhead, pointing out the asynchronous issue I made the following modification to the code and found that it worked. Surprisingly the count that I added doesn't seem to raise above 0, but I am assuming that it was because it was quite a close run  thing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>asynchronous working</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000000;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>


        <script src="build/three.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            //--------------- difference number 1
            var obj_geometry;
            var obj_material;
            var loaded = false;
            //-----------------------------------

            var container;

            var camera, scene, renderer, objects;

            var scaleAdj = 100;
            init();
            animate();

            function init() 
            {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                //-----an info display
                info = document.createElement( 'div' );
                info.id = "info";
                info.style.position = 'absolute';
                info.style.top = '10px';
                info.style.width = '100%';
                info.style.textAlign = 'center';

                container.appendChild(info);
                //-----------------


                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 20000 );
                camera.position.set( 0, 500, 0 );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xcce0ff, 10, 10000 );


                //-------------------difference number 2--------------------
                var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

                loader.load( 'cube.json', function ( geometry, material ) 
                {
                    obj_geometry = geometry;
                    obj_material = material;
                    loaded = true;

                });

                var notLoadedCount = 0;

                var processor = setInterval(function()
                {           
                    if(!loaded)
                    {
                        notLoadedCount++;                   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var faceMaterial = new THREE.MultiMaterial( obj_material);

                        for ( var i = 0; i < 250; i ++ ) 
                        {

                            var x = ( ( i % 27 )  - 13.5 ) * (5 * scaleAdj) + THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 300 * scaleAdj);
                            var z = ( Math.floor( i / 27 ) - 13.5 ) * (5 * scaleAdj) + THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 300 * scaleAdj);

                            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( obj_geometry, faceMaterial);

                            var s = THREE.Math.randFloat( 0.5, 2 ) * scaleAdj;
                            mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );

                            mesh.position.set( x, 0, z );
                            mesh.rotation.y = THREE.Math.randFloat( -0.25, 0.25 );

                            mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                            mesh.updateMatrix();

                            scene.add( mesh );

                            info.innerHTML= '*not loaded count = ' + notLoadedCount;

                        }

                        clearInterval(processor);
                    }
                }, 100);


                //--------------------------------------

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff ) );

                // ground
                var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                var groundTexture = textureLoader.load(  "texture.jpg" );
                groundTexture.wrapS = groundTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                groundTexture.repeat.set( 40, 40 );
                groundTexture.anisotropy = 16;

                var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, specular: 0x111111, map: groundTexture } );

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 20000, 20000 ), groundMaterial );
                mesh.position.y = 0;
                mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add( mesh );

                // Renderer

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color );

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                // Events

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }


            function onWindowResize( event ) {

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();

            }

            function render() {

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }



        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help with this, hopefully it helps others too. If there are any problems with this resolution that anybody notices, please let me know. Thanks.